# Kde 5.12 Kubuntu 18.4 and ScidvsPc

Tags: kubuntu

The background of ScidvsPc is set to dark by Kde, rendering ScidvsPc inoperable. With the settings of ScidvsPc I can not change it. For example, if I take the Desktop Mate, ScidvsPc looks like I know and like it. Where can I adjust the needs at Kde?

Comment: What is ScidvsPc? How can we get it to reproduce your problem?

Comment: ScidvsPc is a chessDB.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/scidvspc/
Install and start.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In the KDE settings, the color scheme is set to Breeze dark. After setting it to Breeze, ScidvsPc sees what I want. This probably happens with any non QT application.
Thank you for your attention.